# How to change text not nested in child tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change text just "24" not "차단".

I used `$("#cnt5").text()` but it doesn't work.

How to?

```
<div class="cntBox link" id="cnt5" data-url="recentStat.php" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span class="cntName">차단</span>
    24
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the text and then remove everything *but numbers*.

```js
// Extract the text
const str = document.getElementById('cnt5').textContent

// Remove everything but numbers
const res = str.replace(/\D+?|([0-9])+?/g, '$1');

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-row-code {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 64px !important
}
```

```html
<div class="cntBox link" id="cnt5" data-url="recentStat.php" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span class="cntName">차단</span> 24
</div>
```